# Find the minimum number of blocks that rollar would cover so that it repairs all damaged blocks?

Tags: dynamic-programming

A road divided in blocks "_ * * _ _ * _ _ _ " where ‘*’ represent damaged block. There is a rollar that is used to repair the road. Rollar is of fixed length K. Given the damaged locations (N) and the size of rollar K. find the minimum number of blocks that rollar would cover so that it repairs all damaged blocks. Rolar may not repair continuously. There can be gaps.[you can read it here.](http://careercup.com/question?id=5677301724348416)

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that the damaged positions are pos[0],pos[1],...,pos[n-1].
Create a dp array. Here, dp[idx] represents the minimum number of blocks the roller will cover to repair damages from index idx to n-1 and it starts from index idx. 
Now, dp[n-1]=k;
For any other index, say i, let us compute dp[i]:
If the roller is kept at pos[i], the roller will cover upto pos[i]+k. Suppose the damaged location after pos[i]+k is at index j.
Now, there are two cases possible. 
1. The roller rolls upto that covering the index j. ans1=dp[j+1]+(pos[j]-pos[i])
2. The roller starts again at index j. ans2=dp[j]+k
Then, dp[i]=min(ans1,ans2)
The index searching can be done using binary search. 
So, the overall time complexity: O(n*log(n)).